# Peak Finder function crashes

Tags: python

I tried writing a peak_finder function that searches a 1D list for a peak. I wrote the same algorithm in JavaScript and it works fine with the same inputs given to my Python algorithms. However, my Python algorithm gives me a `list index out of range error.` Here's the code for my algorithm in Python:

```
def peak_finder(arr):
  mid = len(arr) / 2

  if arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1]:
    return peak_finder(arr[:mid])
  elif arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1]:
    return peak_finder(arr[mid:])
  else:
    return arr[mid]
```

The sample input I used to test it was: `print(peak_finder([0, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]))`.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: `mid = 7/2` should be `mid = 7//2` in python otherwise it would be `3.5`, the index of which would be out of range.

Comment: `mid + 1` is an invalid index for a list of length 2 (`mid == len(arr) / 2 == 2 / 2 == 1`, so `mid + 1 == 2`).

Comment: @bulbus That's *a* problem in Python 3 (or with `from __future__ import division`), but it doesn't cause an "index out of range" error.

Comment: @chepner agree on the error thrown. But it  should still be `7//2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add some length checks:

```
def peak_finder(arr):
  if (len(arr) == 1):
    return arr[mid]
  elif (len(arr) == 2):
    return max(arr[0], arr[1])

  mid = len(arr) / 2

  if arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1]:
    return peak_finder(arr[:mid])
  elif arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1]:
    return peak_finder(arr[mid:])
  else:
    return arr[mid]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to check for array length

```
def peak_finder(arr):
  if len(arr) == 1:  # check
    return arr[0]
  if len(arr) == 2:
    return max(arr[0], arr[1])

  mid = len(arr) / 2

  if arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1]:
    return peak_finder(arr[:mid])
  elif arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1]:
    return peak_finder(arr[mid:])
  else:
    return arr[mid]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But that is still giving me the same error.